# Get all hosts an event via fb api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph, facebook-events

I have a problem to get all host an event on Facebook via fb API. I only get the owner, but some events have more than one and I have to use all in my application. I used the php-API

Have anybody an idea to solve my problem?